# Generic type with constructor in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Suppose I have a class like this

```
export default class Foo {
    id: number;
    code: string;

    constructor(data: any) {
        this.id = data.Id
        this.code = data.Code;
    }
}
```

and I need to write a generic function that would use any class like Foo with a constructor and a any param...

```
import { SPFI } from '@pnp/sp';
import Foo from '../models/foo';

async function get(sp: SPFI, filter: string = '') {
  const items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Foos").items.filter(filter)();
  return items.map((i) => new Foo(i));
}
```

I would like to write it in a generic manner.

I tried

```
async function get<T extends new()?>(sp: SPFI, listTitle: string, filter: string = ''): Promise<T[]> {
    const items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.filter(filter)();
    return items.map((i) => new T(i));
}
```

GPT proposes me to create a new

```
interface Constructable<T> {
  new (data: any): T;
}
```

and

```
async function get<T>(sp: SPFI, listTitle: string, classType: Constructable<T>, filter: string = ''): Promise<T[]> {
  const items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.filter(filter)();
  return items.map((i) => new classType(i));
}
```

Is it the best approach using the current possibilities of typescript (I have TypeScript 9.6.5 installed)?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with passing the type as parameter...

```
async function get<T>(type: { new(...args: any[]): T; }, sp: SPFI, listTitle: string, filter: string = ''): Promise<T[]> {
    const items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.filter(filter)();
    return items.map((i) => new type(i));
}
```